# CPU pipeline stalls visualization

Tags: optimization, cpu, cpu-architecture, instructions

I saw a few graphs and tables showing how well are the CPU instructions interleaved. For example:

```
    time →      total: 7
1   B = a + b   ●   ●   ●               
2   C = c + d       ●   ●   ●           
3   A = B * C           ○   ○   ●   ●   ●
```

which I got from [Playing with the CPU pipeline](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/9/17/playing-with-the-cpu-pipeline).

My question is twofold: how to find out the stalls in the first place, and how to visualize them in a readable way? I mean, what software is used to look at and optimize code at such level?

Answer (score 1):

Short: In most cases, no software is used to "look at the stalls". Stalls are predictable, and can be found without even touching a computer. You know when they will happen, and you can draw them however you like.

Full story:

First of all you have to understand pipelining.

Each "action" that has to be taken to process an instruction, is executed on separate hardware (seperate parts of your CPU). If there are 7 steps, you could be handling 7 instructions at the same time.
[image]

(source: http://www.phatcode.net/res/260/files/html/CPUArchitecturea3.html)

This image visualizes this pipelining. You can see multiple instructions shifting through the CPU.As soon as instruction 1's opcode is retrieved, it doesn't need the opcode hardware anymore. Instruction 2's opcode can now be retrieved. This goes the same for all other blocks.
The important thing to notice here, is to see that values for instruction 2 are loaded before instruction 1 finished. This is possible, if the values of instruction 2 do not depend on instruction 1. If they do depend on instruction 1, instruction 2 needs to be stalled. It will wait at its place. Instead of at T5, values will be retrieved at T6. At this point instruction 1 has stored its result, so instruction 2 can proceed.

This is what you see with 1 and 2. They're independent, allowing to execute the next instruction without any stalls. However, 3 depends on 1 and 2. This means it has to wait until both results are stored.

To answer your question now: 
How did we know? We saw it, without using any tool. How did we visualise it? The same way we would visualise any other data, meaning you can choose which way, as long as it's clear to understand.

Please note that this is a simplified answer, in order to make it understandable. Pipelining and processor optimizations are way more advanced in modern computers. For example, there are (conditional) jumps, which can cause instruction 2,3,4 to be skipped, and all of a sudden another instruction has to be loaded in the pipeline due to the jump. You can find a lot about this (both simplified and advanced), when searching for pipelining.

More detailed information on this topic:
http://www.phatcode.net/res/260/files/html/CPUArchitecturea3.html section 4.8.2. (This is what I found while googling to refresh my memory, but it looks like pretty good information)

Comment: Ok, but different instructions have difference latencies and "complexities", I presume. So I thought there is some king of software which takes all the intricacies into account so I don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: Indeed, some instructions are more complex than others. Instruction sets for different CPUs contain this information (along with more details and limitations). However, this is something that (as far as I know) only compilers need. Therefore there aren't that much tools for it I guess. 
The only thing I can find is http://www.teach-sim.com/ .
Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: The kind of optimization mentioned in the linked article got me interested in how it's done...

Comment: Most of this is quite theoretical, and there are hundreds of articles on it on the internet, though you might need to search for one that fits your needs (not too simple or too complicated). During my studies, we used the book Structured Computer Organisation, which is about all computer internals, but also provided good insights in these CPU optimizations. https://www.pearson.ch/HigherEducation/Pearson/EAN/9780273769248/Structured-Computer-Organization-International-Edition

Search tips on this topic: cpu branch prediction, instruction pipelining optimization, Out-of-order execution